# How to get the date time from template into component

Tags: angular, angular-date-format

I am using datetime pipe to format the time and displaying in template. But I want to get the same time in my component. How to achieve this?

Here is the stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sb3ekr

I want to get the displayed date time in app.component.ts using some variable. Please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DatePipe in your component.

```
var tmp = new DatePipe('en-Us').transform(this.today, 'dd:MM:yyyy hh-mm-ss');
```

Comment: Thanks, it is easier.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using ViewChild and ElementRef,
 here it is what I have changed,

HTML,

```
<span #dtime> {{ today | date :'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss'}}</span>
```

Component,

```
today: number = Date.now();
  dateT: string = undefined;

@ViewChild("dtime", {read: ElementRef}) dtime: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dateT = this.dtime.nativeElement.textContent;
 // console.log(this.dtime.nativeElement.textContent);
  console.log(this.dateT);
  }
```